# How to apply 'layout' only when element is bigger than 500px? (angular material 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, flexbox, angular-material2

I am developing application with angular material2.

And I want to make `layout="row"` when element is bigger than 500px and `layout="column"` when it is smaller.

P.S. It both could be on big resolution. So it is not related to resolution.

Comment: When is an element becoming bigger than 500px? What causes it to become bigger?

Comment: I make it via typescript.

Comment: https://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, the flex layout team made a [very comprehensive documentation](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Custom-Breakpoints), maybe you could take a look at it before asking ?

They allow you to make your own custom breakpoints. Although I do not recommend it (they thought about those breakpoints), you can change them, and also get the width with the Observable Media ([documentation that you can find here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ObservableMedia))

Comment: Please, remove comment, I want to delete question.